# Stream telegram channel contents to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, telegram

I want to show my telegram channel contents in my wordpress website.
Is any way exist for stream telegram channel contents to my wordpress?

Comment: Please share your code/workaround

Comment: i dont start any coding yet! i just have an idea.

Comment: Currently channel messages can't be read by a bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with Telegram [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots). Basic idea:

1. Create a bot that can post to your channel;
2. Create an interaction layer between your site and the bot (for example, [REST API](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/));
3. Post something **via your bot**;
4. As soon as you post, your bot should send the post to **both** channel and website.

Also this can be done with the [console client](https://github.com/vysheng/tg/tree/test) (`channel_history` command).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin : 'TelegramsChannelToWP'

1. first you must get API-key from :
   [http://en.tele-wall.ir/api/register/](http://en.tele-wall.ir/)
2. then enter your site and your favorite channel
3. install plugin TelegramsChannelToWp
4. in setting page enter api-key and channel's username
5. add TelegramsChannelToWp widget.
6. Finish

https://github.com/mahdizolqadr/TelegramsChannelToWP

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [WP Telegram](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wptelegram/). It works very well from WP to telegram; moreover, it provides widget to show telegram channel or group on WP.